# How do I post to Facebook a group of Links?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-graph-api

I know how to use Facebook Open Graph to create a wall post on any chosen member, however, I don't know how some applications post something like this:

[image: Example:]

The 'description' parameter contains 3 different urls. At first I thought they were posting HTML into the 'description' but it turned out Facebook blocks them in the first place.

Is there some hidden undocumented features of the Facebook API they are using? May be the old API had this but the new Open Graph doesnt?

The facebook app:
http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=20678178440

Facebook Post entity:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking to use HTML? The "default" Wall is plain text. As far as I know you need to install an app to add HTML to your FB wall. Check out the app [Advanced Wall](http://www.whatapps.com/2007/11/27/the-12-walls-of-facebook-part-1/) to get HTML functionality.

Comment: That's not what I meant, I want to post to a wall through my own APP that uses facebook open graph.

Comment: See this for more info [link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)